# VS2012 and VS2013 Missing STS Web Application Template

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web, asp.net-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I am trying to create STS MVC web application in VS2012 and VS2013, but STS web template is not available in template gallery.  Is there a way that I can download STS web app template in VS2012 and Vs2013 ?

One more query, We have Identity and Access tool in VS2012 but there is nothing like this in VS2013.
How I can install Identity and Access tool in VS2013 ?

Please help me.

Comment: You would do better breaking these up into two questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Q and A for the Identity and Access Tool extension for VS 2012, you will see a post from a member of the team who indicates that it will not be ported to VS 2013.  They have added support for claims based authentication directly into the ASP.NET project creation template.

In the post, they admit that they are not 100% equivalent, so they use VS2012 and VS2013 side by side until they achieve parity.

[Identity and Access Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e)